# data undefined in jquery autocomplete function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete, opencart2.x

I am trying to make a auto-suggest search field in opencart 2.0 version and i did it many times but now i got data undefined error. I spent 9 hour but unable to fix it. Just Look at my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
$("#advancesearchvalue").autocomplete({
 'source': function(request, response) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=common/advancesearch/autocomplete',
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
    data: "productname="+$('#advancesearchvalue').val(),
    dataType: 'json',  
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('.jquery_loading').removeClass('dispaly_none');
    },  
    complete: function() {
      $('.jquery_loading').addClass('dispaly_none');
    },     
    success: function(json) {
  $('.gifimagelocality').addClass('displaynone');
      response($.map(json, function(item) {
        return {
          label: item['name'],
          href:item['href']
        }
      }));
    }
  });
},
'select': function(item) {
    $('#advancesearchvalue').val(item.name);
},
}).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul,item) {
  return $("<li>")
    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
    .append("<a class='navsearch' href='"+item['href']+"'>" + item['label']+ "</a>")
    .appendTo(ul);
};
});
```

And the result is

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="top: 46px; left: 0px; display: none;">
<li data-value="undefined">
<a href="#">Apple Cinema 30"</a>
</li>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks For your time. I got this problem due to another jquery plugin. The mention code is working fine.